# Reactive Extensions (Rx) - subscribe to mouse position data only while a key is held down

Tags: wpf, events, system.reactive

In WPF I would like to subscribe to the mouse position points only while a key is held down. I then want to set the captured points onto a property, only when the key is released (i.e. when I have a full set of the captured points) and continue listening for the next key down/up combination to create another capture of mouse positions, etc.

My interpretation of the above is that I need to trigger a sequence when a key is down and stop taking when a key is released, but I want the OnNext to receive a set of mouse points.

From a fair amount of reading (I'm new to Rx) I've put together the following pseudo/real sample:

```
var keyDownSeq = Observable.FromEvent(...);
var keyUpSeq = Observable.FromEvent(...);
var mouseMoveSeq = Observable.FromEvent(...);

var mouseMovesWhileKeyDown = keyDownSeq
    .Where(keyEventArgs => keyEventArgs.IsRepeat == false) //WPF fires the same KeyDown repeatedly
    .Where(keyEventArgs => keyEventArgs.Key == Key.Space)
    .Select(_ => mouseMoveSeq
                    .TakeUntil(keyUpSeq)
                    .ToList())
    .Subscribe(listOfMousePoints => MyProperty = listOfMousePoints);
```

1. Will the above do what I think it will and create a list of mouse points that were encountered while the Space bar is held down? Do I need to call ToList() where I do, or should I do this in the Subscribe?
2. If I remove the second Where clause (allowing any key(s) to be pressed to begin a capture) how can I prevent a second, or third, key being held down and causing duplicates in the resulting sequence?

Thank you.

**Edit**

Would it be completely incorrect to do the following using a local variable?

- Set a local variable to the KeyDown sequence value in the Select()
- Reset the local variable to null when the KeyUpSeq encounters the same key
- Filter the KeyDownSeq to ignore all values while this variable has value
- Filter the KeyUpSeq to ignore all KeyUp values that don't match the local variable

Does Rx have a concept of such a local state variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to be careful with race conditions here.**

With some setup.

```
IObservable<Unit> keyDown = Observable.FromEvent(/*keydown*/).Select(_=>true);
IObservable<Unit> keyUp = Observable.FromEvent(/*keyup*/).Select(_=>false);

IObservable<Point> mouseMoves = Observable.FromEvent(...);
```

Now create an observable that we know will start with a keyDown event

```
var keys = keyDown.Merge(keyUp).DistinctUntilChanged().SkipWhile(_=>!_);
```

Use this observable to create a window.

```
IOBservable<IObservable<Point> mousePaths = 
    mouseMoves
       .Window(keys)
       .Where((_,i)=>i%2==0);
```

Note that we want to skip the odd windows. Even windows are key down. Odd windows are key up.

Now there are no race conditions and we will never miss a keyDown or keyUp event.

*Explanation* If you use the other overload of Window, the one with a seperate open and closing trigger, the problem is that the closing trigger generation is lazy. It is not generated and does not subscribe to it's source until the opening edge of the window is triggered. That means there is a small time window for a keyUp event to occur before the window closing trigger is registered.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Can you clarify how the call to window works? I understand the race condition issue, but to me it looks like the window closing selector will never produce a value as the SkipUntil method will never produce a value. What am I not understanding?

Comment: SkipUntil will skip all values until the source sequence produces true. Then it will produce values for ever. 'true, false, true, false, true, false' for ever alternating. You could read it as ``SkipUntil(value=>value==true)`` if you like

Comment: In this case the Window selector is used for both closing ``and`` opening which is why we start the sequence with the item that should open it. The next will close it. The next after that will open it and so on.

Comment: Marked as answer, but do you have a link to any documentation on this overload of Window? I'm on mobile, but couldn't see anything on MSDN and it's only alluded to here http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html Also could I swap in Buffer as I only need the values as a list on KeyUp?Thanks very much.

Comment: The link is here but I've misread the doc. https://gist.github.com/bradphelan/9109315 The method closes then immediately opens a new window upon boundary events. To fix it is easy. I'll do it now.

Comment: Strange however. The method is not documented here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.window(v=vs.103).aspx Must be a recent addition to the library.

Comment: Yeah you should be able to use ``Buffer`` as there is an identical method which takes an observable for triggering buffer boundaries.

Comment: This raised in my mind a more general problem which I posted as a question here as I can't figure out how to solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904898/how-to-select-head-and-tail-at-the-same-time-in-reactive-extensions

Comment: Regarding your explanation of SkipUntil - this method doesn't take a predicate as far as I can see? It either takes a DateTime offset value, or an observable sequence (and will only start producing values when this other sequence produces a value). Would it be sufficient to use the keyDown sequence again for this, or is there a race condition that way? Thanks.

Comment: My bad. Should be using SkipWhile which does have a predicate overload. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways to simplify you setup. The first is to create a single `IObservable<bool>` that emits exactly when your key switches between down or up position.

```
//true means key down, false means key up
IObservable<bool> keyChange =
    Observable.Merge(
        Observable.FromEvent(/*keyDown*/).Select(_ => true),
        Observable.FromEvent(/*keyUp*/).Select(_ => false))
    .DistinctUntilChanged();
```

This is what the histories will look like, where a `x` is an event firing, a `T` or `F` is a boolean, and left to right is increasing time.

```
keyDown    -----xxxxxxxx--------xxxxxxx------xxxxxxxxxxxxx----
keyUp      xxxxx--------xxxxxxxx-------xxxxxx-------------xxxx
keyChange  F----T-------F-------T------F-----T------------F---
```

The second is to use `Observable.Window` to pull out contiguous sequences of mouse moves between key down "window openings" and key up "window closings."

```
IObservable<Point> mouseMoves = Observable.FromEvent(...);

IObservable<IObservable<Point>> mousePaths = mouseMoves.Window(
    keyChange.Where(b => b),
    _ => keyChange.Where(b => !b));
```

Documentation for methods used:

- [Observable.DistinctUntilChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229494%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)
- [Observable.Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211621%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

The signature for `Window` can be a little scary at first, but once you understand it it's fairly simple to use.

Comment: Thank you - very informative, but I have a few questions:    1.How would you deal with two keys being held down and then one released? The keyChange sequence would show false again, no?    2. Am I correct in thinking that I could then subscribe to mousePaths and in the OnNext call ToList() on the windowed IObservable so that I can then set my property to this list?    3.It doesn't look like it, but does Buffer have the OpeningSelector and ClosingSelector overloads? I am asking as buffer gives me an IObservable<List<Point>> which I want anyway.

Comment: @Julius 1. What about two keys? I don't understand the question.  Maybe make a separate one and post the link here?  2. Yes, that's exactly what you would do with the result of Window. 3. Buffer would work here as well.  The difference in behavior is the following.  Window will emit an observable the moment each window starts, and each window will emit its contents as they are produced by the source.  Buffer will emit each "window" at the *end* of it, all at once as a List.  Buffer is useful when you want to do batch processing.

Comment: Isn't there a race condition here? ``KeyDown`` causes the window to open. The selector is invoked and ``_ => keyChange.Where(b => !b)`` is called to register the window closing observable. However, because ``keyChange`` is hot, there could be a keyUp event inbetween the keyDown and the registering of the window closing detection. Essentially in this case the window will stay open.

Comment: I've posted a correct answer with no race conditions below. I've given a -1 to the above answer as I think it could result in hard to discover bugs if used as is.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Inappropriate use of downvote. You copied my answer with one modification, evident in the fact that you used identical variable names. That modification I absolutely can appreciate because you make a good point about the problem in this answer, and I would agree it should be marked as answer because of that correction. But my answer is still useful, especially because I brought the asker 90% of the way to the solution. The only error here is in subtle behavior of this `Window` overload.

Comment: The reason I down voted was because it is not just wrong but dangerous.  Race conditions are extremely hard to figure out once in the code. Down voting is anonymous obviously because the recipient trends to whinge and dispute afterwards I guess.