# How to Select Head and Tail at the same time in Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive, race-condition

I would like to create the following combinator

```
public static IObservable<U> HeadTailSelect<T, U>
    (this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, IObservable<T>, U> fn)
{

}
```

The selector method should be passed the current event and an observable to all future events, the tail. It **must be guaranteed** that upon subscribing to the tail any time in the future the first received event will be the very next one that was received after the head.

I'm aware that this will require some buffering but I'm not quite sure how to put this together.

This has some nice properties. You can do

```
IObservable<IObservable<Unit>> windows =
source
    .HeadTailSelect((h,tail)=>Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .TakeUntil(tail)
        .Select(_=>Unit.Default)
    )
```

and avoid race conditions whereby within the window it takes `TakeUntil` to be registered after responding to the first event you miss some events.

Also **bonus karma** for any ideas on how to test the implementation.

The following test case is necessary for the implementation to satisfy though it may not be sufficient to prove if race conditions are avoided.

```
public class HeadTailSelect : ReactiveTest
{
    TestScheduler _Scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    [Fact]
    public void ShouldWork()
    {

        var o = _Scheduler.CreateColdObservable
            (OnNext(10, "A")
            , OnNext(11, "B")
            , OnNext(12, "C")
            , OnNext(13, "D")
            , OnNext(14, "E")
            , OnNext(15, "F")
            , OnCompleted<string>(700)
            );

        var data = o.HeadTailSelect((head, tail) => tail.Take(2).ToList())
            .SelectMany(p=>p)
            .Select(l=>String.Join("-", l));


        var actual = _Scheduler.Start(() =>
            data
        , created: 0
        , subscribed: 1
        , disposed: 1000
        );

        actual.Messages.Count()
                .Should()
                .Be(7);

        var messages = actual.Messages.Take(6)
                             .Select(v => v.Value.Value)
                             .ToList();

        messages[0].Should().Be("B-C");
        messages[1].Should().Be("C-D");
        messages[2].Should().Be("D-E");
        messages[3].Should().Be("E-F");
        messages[4].Should().Be("F");
        messages[5].Should().Be("");

    }
}
```

Comment: When and how often will `HeadTailSelect` call the selector?

Comment: Once per element. It should pass the current element and an observable representing all future elements. The selector can then combine the head and the tail into a new object of type U and return it. Most likely U will be a Task or IObservable. I have a test case that will make it clearer.

Comment: i've added a solution below. it passes the above test but i'm not 100% sure what it's limitations are.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a candidate solution which passes the above test. However I'm not rock certain that it satisfies requirements.

```
/// <summary>
/// Pass the head and tail of the observable to the
/// selector function. Note that 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="U"></typeparam>
/// <param name="source"></param>
/// <param name="fn"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IObservable<U> HeadTailSelect<T, U>
    (this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, IObservable<T>, U> fn)
{
    var tail = new Subject<T>();
    return Observable.Create<U>(observer =>
    {
        return source.Subscribe(v =>
        {
            tail.OnNext(v);
            var u = fn(v, tail);
            observer.OnNext(u);

        }
        ,e=> { tail.OnCompleted();observer.OnError(e);  }
        ,()=> { tail.OnCompleted();observer.OnCompleted();  });
    });
}
```

Note that `u` is most likely to be some kind of `IObservable` and should be subscribed to immediately. If this is done I think everything should be ok.

Comment: That seems like a nice solution.  Only thing I'd suggest is moving your declaration of `tail` to be inside your `Observable.Create` lambda, otherwise the observable produced by `HeadTailSelect` only works correctly for a single subscriber.